# AJAX submit both ENTER and CLICK

Tags: ajax, forms, submit

So I have a form to submit user login data. But currently the default of data submitting is by clicking a button. This script can work both click the button or pressing ENTER on Mozilla, but not in Chrome. How to resolve my problem?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#buttonSignIn').click(function(s){

                s.preventDefault();

                var error     = false;
                var _wait_    = $(this).attr('data-wait');
                var user      = $('#user').val();
                var pass      = $('#password_signin').val();
                var waitHtml  = $(this).html();
                var _wait     = '...';
                var _waitHtml = waitHtml + _wait;

                if( user == '' || user == 0 || trim( user ).length  == 0 ) {
                    var error = true;
                    $('#user').focus();
                }

                if( error == false ){
                    $('#buttonSignIn').attr({'disabled' : 'true'}).html(_waitHtml).css({'opacity':'0.5'});

                    $.post("asset/ajax/sign_in.php", $("#signin_form").serialize(),function(result){

                        if( result == 'True' ){
                             $('#signin_form input, .forgot, #buttonSignIn, #recover_pass_form').remove();
                             $('#success_signin').fadeIn(500).html(_wait_);
                             $('#error').fadeOut(500);
                             $("#signin_form").reset();

                            $('body,html').animate({
                                scrollTop: 0
                            }, 500);

                             setTimeout(function()
                             {
                                window.location.reload();

                              },500 );
                        }
                        else{
                             $('#error').fadeIn(500);
                             $('#error').html( result );
                             $("#signin_form").reset();
                             $('#buttonSignIn').removeAttr('disabled').html(waitHtml).css({'opacity': 1});
                        }//<-- ELSE
                    });//<-- END $POST AJAX
                }//<-- END ERROR == FALSE
            });//<-- END FUNCTION CLICK
}

                        <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="signin_form" class="form_login signInForm">
                            <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['placeholder_email_username']; ?>" title="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['placeholder_email_username']; ?>" />
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password_signin" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['placeholder_pass']; ?>" title="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['placeholder_pass']; ?>" />
                            <span id="error"></span>
                            <span id="success_signin"></span>
                            <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="recover_pass buttonInside forgot buttonForgot"><?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['placeholder_forgot_pass']; ?></a>
                            <button type="submit" id="buttonSignIn" class="button_class" data-wait="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['please_wait']; ?>"><span><?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['sign_in']; ?></span></button>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        </form>
```